# Query node postgres does not work in docker

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, node-postgres

When I send a request to the server it seems that the query function is not executing therefore no data is returned from the server, that is when it is running in a docker container, because when I run without the docker container the query is executed correctly, besides if I use for example knex.js in docker other queries run correctly, some idea of what the problem might be

```
var client = new Client(process.env.POSTGRES_URI);
client.connect();    
router.post('/interruption', function(req, res) {
      let data = req.body;
      let area=data[0];
      let base = `SELECT * FROM interruption
                  INNER JOIN lnk_operator ON id_ope1=id_ope3
                  WHERE LOWER(area) SIMILAR TO LOWER(${area})`;
      var query = client.query(new Query(base));
      query.on("row", function(row, result) {
        result.addRow(row);
      });
      query.on("end", function(result) {
        res.json({info:result});
      });
    });
```

Here attach my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  # Backend API
  sma-api:
    container_name: backend_sma_api
    build: ./
    command: npm start
    working_dir: /usr/src/sma_api
    environment:
      POSTGRES_URI: postgres://postgres:secret_password@postgres:5432/sma_api
      REDIS_URI:  redis://redis:6379
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  postgres:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret_password
      POSTGRES_DB: sma_api
      POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
    build: ./postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: Check that your Postgres container has init data and access for remote connections

Comment: When I use `docker exec -it sma_api_postgres_1 psql -U postgres` to enter the postgres container, I have access to the data and manipulate them normally...

Comment: I seem to have overlooked this warning `(node:30) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.23.0.3:5432`, I do not know how I can correct it...